# Check whether Pandas DataFrame column contains duplicates within floating point precision

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, floating-point, precision

I have a dataframe, `df`, of xyz points with 4 columns, `x`, `y`, `z`, and `Classification` , all containing floats. The dataframe was created by concatenating two other dataframes, `df1` and `df2`.

All of the points in `df2` are a subset of those in `df1`, but the two dataframes underwent different processing in different software. All of the points in `df2` have a classification of 14.  None of the points in `df1` are of class 14.  Thus in df there are points that are *essentially* xyz duplicates (the number of these xyz duplicates is `len(df2)`) half of which are class 14.  I want to find these duplicates and discard those that are not class 14.

I say the rows are *essentially* xyz duplicates because floating point error has been introduced to many of the rows during the previous processing.

```
>>> # make example data,
>>> # small differences introduced on 2nd data
>>> x1 = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0])
>>> x2 = x1[:4] + np.array([0, 0, 3e-13, 0])

>>> y1 = np.array([10.0, 11.01, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0])
>>> y2 = y1[:4] + np.array([0, 0, 3e-13, 4e-13])

>>> z1 = np.array([10.0, 10.1, 10.2, 10.3, 10.4, 10.5, 10.6])
>>> z2 = z1[:4] + np.array([0.0, 0.0, 3e-13, 4e-13])

>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x', 'y', 'z', 'Classification'])
>>> df1['x'] = x1
>>> df1['y'] = y1
>>> df1['z'] = z1
>>> df1['Classifcation'] = 0

>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x', 'y', 'z', 'Classification'])
>>> df2['x'] = x2
>>> df2['y'] = y2
>>> df2['z'] = z2
>>> df2['Classifcation'] = 14

>>> df1
     x      y     z  Classification
0  0.0  10.00  10.0               0
1  1.0  11.01  10.1               0
2  2.0  12.00  10.2               0
3  3.0  13.00  10.3               0
4  4.0  14.00  10.4               0
5  5.0  15.00  10.5               0
6  6.0  16.00  10.6               0

>>> df2
     x    y             z  Classification
0  0.0  0.0  3.000000e-13              14
1  1.0  1.0  1.000000e+00              14
2  2.0  2.0  2.000000e+00              14
3  3.0  3.0  3.000000e+00              14

>>> df = pd.concat ([df1, df2], axis=0)
>>> df
     x      y             z  Classification
0  0.0  10.00  1.000000e+01               0
1  1.0  11.01  1.010000e+01               0
2  2.0  12.00  1.020000e+01               0
3  3.0  13.00  1.030000e+01               0
4  4.0  14.00  1.040000e+01               0
5  5.0  15.00  1.050000e+01               0
6  6.0  16.00  1.060000e+01               0
0  0.0   0.00  3.000000e-13              14
1  1.0   1.00  1.000000e+00              14
2  2.0   2.00  2.000000e+00              14
3  3.0   3.00  3.000000e+00              14
```

Originally I tried

```
>>> df0 = df.loc[~((df.duplicated(subset=['x', 'y', 'z'],
                          keep=False))
                 & (df.Classification != 14))]

>>> df0
     x      y     z  Classification
2  2.0  12.00  10.2               0
3  3.0  13.00  10.3               0
4  4.0  14.00  10.4               0
5  5.0  15.00  10.5               0
6  6.0  16.00  10.6               0
0  0.0  10.00  10.0              14
1  1.0  11.01  10.1              14
2  2.0  12.00  10.2              14
3  3.0  13.00  10.3              14

>>> len(df), len(df0)
(11, 9)
```

This discarded all of the non-14-classifed **exact** duplicates, but missed the close (in x, y, and z) duplicates created by the floating point error.

I need to do something like `df.duplicated` but with the behavior of `numpy.isclose` so that values within a certain tolerance will be considered duplicates.

Thanks

Comment: Will you please show some samples of your dataframes? It'll make it a lot easier to help :)

Comment: I added some example data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to do this is to remove the duplicates before the concat, as I understand you are trying to remove rows in df1 that are already in df2. The trick here is to use isin and create a key that can compare two data frames easily, and you can use string format and set decimal points (example below uses 5 points).

```
df_1['key'] = df_1.apply(lambda row: f'{row["X"]:.5f}-{row["Y"]:.5f}-{row["Z"]:.5f}', axis=1)
df_2['key'] = df_2.apply(lambda row: f'{row["X"]:.5f}-{row["Y"]:.5f}-{row["Z"]:.5f}', axis=1)
df_1 = df_1[df_1['key'].isin(df_2['key'])==False]
combined = pd.concat([df_1, df_2])
```